# cancelling fetch method within an observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, fetch, unsubscribe

I want to cancel the fetch method when unsubscribe to the subscription of the returned observable

so why should I  return ()=>controller.abort()

why this method just invoked when I unsubscribe()

```
createHttp(url: string) {
return new Observable((observer) => {
  const controller = new AbortController()
  const signal = controller.signal
  fetch(url, { signal })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((body) => {
      observer.next(body);
      observer.complete();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      observer.error(error);
    });
   return ()=>controller.abort()
});
```

}

if I just return it without the es6 function like that

```
 return controller.abort()
```

it cancel the fetch method if I just subscribe()

Comment: You may be interested in the [fromFetch](https://rxjs.dev/api/fetch/fromFetch) Observable.

Comment: @SamHerrmann this isn't what I want I asking about relation between the return value of an observable and the unsubscribe method !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of an Observable needs to be a reference to a function that the Observable can call when the subscriber unsubscribes. With `return controller.abort()`, you are not returning a reference to the abort function, you are calling the abort function and returning its return value. With `return () => controller.abort()` on the other hand, you are not calling the function, you are returning the function itself that the Observable can call on unsubscribe.

Consider the following example:

```
let sayHello = () => "Hello"

function exampleOne() {
  // return reference to sayHello function.
  return sayHello;
}

// vs

function exampleTwo() {
  // call sayHello function and return its value ("Hello").
  return sayHello();
}
```

## Edit

This edit is based on comment below.

The following is the skeleton for creating an Observable:

```
new Observable((observer) => {
  // Invoked on subscribe.
  return () => {
    // Invoked on unsubscribe.
  }
});
```

Comment: so the returned reference function invoked when unsubscribe only and not when subscribe ?
if yes .. then why not invokes when subscribe too !?

Comment: Yes, the returned function is only invoked when the subscriber unsubscribes. I am not sure what you're asking. If you want to invoke a function on subscribe, then place that before the returned function. Please see edit in my answer.

Comment: I used what you did in the edit but when I return a function that console.log('ddd') the text printed in the console even i subscribe !!? and this doesn't match what u said  now :(

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4rjryb?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Comment: I got your example . but can you look in my code 
regardless the fetch  it printed the text to the console
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ftcqpt?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts)

Comment: Your code works as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qwzxzt?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts. 1. Subscribe, 2. Make HTTP request, 3. Complete Observable. Maybe you're not understanding that calling `observer.complete()` also unsubscribes the observer?

Comment: Maybe you're not understanding that calling observer.complete() also unsubscribes the observer?
...
those words woke me up . ty for your help <3